Best practice for storing access and refresh tokens
I have an Angular UI with a node.js backend where users authenticate with a third-party API.
When the user logs in, an access token and refresh token are returned from the third party, and these are used for future communications with that third party software.
This is a piece of work for a small company, and is implemented on a hosting platform using cPanel.
The UI doesn't need to have any contact with the tokens: that can all be done in my node.js backend. With this in mind, what is the best practice for storing the tokens? Encrypted in a local database, or some other option? Or, would it make more sense to let the tokens hit the UI and store them in local session-based storage?
Thanks

If it's just a user and two tokens, you could use a JSON file and avoid a db. Session vs. JWT Authentication.
